# Optimization application trying to understand the wording

Tags: calculus

[image]

This problem I encountered, and Im trying to figure out. what is the meaning of a channel?

Comment: See the first [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/channel).

Comment: I think they mean something else in this problem for channel? Do they mean like a bridge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short boat that can enter the channel
[image: A short boat that can enter the channel]

A long boat that cannot enter the channel
[image: A long boat that cannot enter the channel]

The maximum length of a boat?

Sorry that I drew boats as lines. Too much simplified. But it will help to solve the problem.